# When saving an image as a PNG or JPEG, does photoshop/GIMP only save the top layers or all the data?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, layers, photo-editing

I need to send a file to someone but it has sensitive information on it that I would not like to share.  I was going to just scan the document and edit out the sensitive information with a layer covering the sensitive information, but I wonder if this is acceptable.  For example, if someone were to intercept the file and read the data to unmask the information that is being hid.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When image is saved as PNG or JPEG, image is flat file there are no layers involved, so your recipient will be not able to view work you have done to hide sensitive information.

Answer (score 3):

It will only save the visible content no matter which layer is on top...hidden/un visible content will not be saved in .PNG and .JPEG